# PyInstaller: Error when executing .exe file from a python file with Sun-valley tkinter theme

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have tried to convert a python file called `gui.py`, shown below, to a single, executable file called `number_generator.exe` using PyInstaller. I have used Python 3.11.4 and PyInstaller 5.13.0.

**gui.py**

```
import tkinter as tk
import sv_ttk
from tkinter import ttk, font, messagebox
from num_gen import number_generator
from check_string_func import check_string


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Frontend of GUI
        self.title("Number Generator")
        self.geometry("600x280")
        self.iconbitmap("dice.ico")

        fontFamilyH1 = font.Font(size = 40)
        fontFamilyH2 = font.Font(size = 25)

        appLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Number Generator", font = fontFamilyH1)        

        # Input fields
        inputFrame = ttk.Frame(self, style = 'styledFrame.TFrame')

        self.startValue = tk.StringVar()
        startEntry = ttk.Entry(inputFrame, textvariable = self.startValue, width = 5, font = fontFamilyH2)
        startLabel = ttk.Label(inputFrame, text = "Start value:", font = fontFamilyH2)

        self.endValue = tk.StringVar()
        endEntry = ttk.Entry(inputFrame, textvariable = self.endValue, width = 5, font = fontFamilyH2)
        endLabel = ttk.Label(inputFrame, text = "End value:", font = fontFamilyH2)

        # Generate button
        generateButton = ttk.Button(self, text = "Generate", style = 'Accent.TButton', width = 15, command = self.buttonAction) 
        
        # Displays widgets to GUI
        appLabel.pack(pady = "15")
        inputFrame.pack()
        startLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 0)
        startEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 0, padx = 2)
        endLabel.grid(column = 0, row = 1)
        endEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        generateButton.pack(pady = "25")

    def buttonAction(self):
        if not self.startValue.get() or not self.endValue.get(): # Checks if there are any values in startvalue and endvalue
            messagebox.showerror(title = "No value(s)", message = "Please input value(s) for start value and end value.")
            return
        
        if not check_string(self.startValue.get()) or not check_string(self.endValue.get()): # Checks if start value and end value are integers
            messagebox.showerror(title = "Non-integer value(s)", message = "Start value and end value have to be a number, please try again.")
            return
            
        if int(self.startValue.get()) >= int(self.endValue.get()): # Checks if start value is greater than end value
            messagebox.showerror(title = "Invalid intervall", message = "End value has to be greater than start value, please try again.")
            return
            
        numbers = number_generator(int(self.startValue.get()), int(self.endValue.get())) # Initiates when every condition is met
        
        for number in range(len(numbers)):
            messagebox.showinfo(title = "Random numbers", message = f"Random number ({number + 1}): {numbers[number]}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Application()
    sv_ttk.set_theme("dark")
    root.mainloop()
```

The command I used for packaging of the file was the following: `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=dice.ico --add-data "dice.ico;." -n number_generator --hidden-import=sv-ttk gui.py`

However, upon execution of `number_generator.exe`, I receive an error that states: `Failed to execute script 'gui' due to unhandled exception: couldn't read file "C:\Users\ben\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI218962\sv_ttk\sv.tcl" no such file or directory`

According to the Github page for the Sun-valley-ttk-theme (https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme), the installation process uses the following pip command: `pip install sv-ttk` which I have done and the script worked flawlessly before packaging with PyInstaller.

But the question is: how do you solve the execution error fron the `number_generator.exe` file? I have tried searching for a solution but haven't found one. I would be very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `--collect-data sv_ttk` option as mentioned [here](https://github.com/rdbende/Sun-Valley-ttk-theme/issues/38#issuecomment-1188761568)?

Comment: No, I didn't and it worked! Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.